# How can I specify as return type of a method the type of the object upon which the method is called?

Tags: java, generics, return-type

Let's say I have an Interface 'Inter', and Inter has a method

```
Inter someMethod();
```

How can I specify that the type of the return object has to be the same as the object upon which the method is called?
So if I have two classes 'C1' and 'C2' that implement Inter, if an instance of C1 calls someMethod (`c1.someMethod()`) the result will be an instance of C1, whereas if an instance of C2 calls someMethod the result will be an instance of C2.

How about parameters? If Inter has a second method

```
void someMethod2(Inter inter)
```

How can I specify that the parameter has to be an instance of the same class as the object calling the method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using *Generics*.

```
public interface Inter<T> {

    T someMethod();
    void someMethod2(T obj);

}

public class C1 implements Inter<C1> {

    public C1 someMethod() {
      // ..
    }

    public void someMethod2(C1 obj) {
      // ..
    }

}

public class C2 implements Inter<C2> {

    public C2 someMethod() {
      // ..
    }

    public void someMethod2(C2 obj) {
      // ..
    }

}
```

***Reference** :*
[Generic Types (The Java™ Tutorials > Generics)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

***Edit** : (Using a bounded generic type; in response to OP's comments)*

```
public interface Inter<T extends Inter<T>> {

    T someMethod();
    void someMethod2(T obj);
}

public class C1 implements Inter<C1> {

    public C1 someMethod() {
        return new C1();
    }

    public void someMethod2(C1 obj) {
      // ..
    }
}

public class C2 implements Inter<C3> { // ERROR
    ..
}
```

But, here comes the catch.

```
public class C2 implements Inter<C1> { // COMPILES!
    ..
}
```

Because, `C1` also satisfies `T extends Inter<T>`. This is as far as this can go I believe.

***Reference** :*
[Bounded Type Parameters (The Java™ Tutorials > Generics)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Comment: This does the trick. One thing though:
"public class C1 implements Inter<C1>"
Could I force here that "C1" can't implement a different Inter other than Inter<C1>?

Comment: That's by design. You'll receive a compiler error if you try: C1 implements Inter<C1>, Inter<C2> But, if you mean to prevent: C1 implements Inter<C2> I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I mean that you would get a compile error if you tried "C1 implements Inter<C2>", or, in general, "X implements Inter<Y>". Because, with this approach, the interface itself is not forcing that the return type of someMethod() has to be the same as the type of the object that calls the method.

Comment: You could however look into Bounded Generic Types. I think you should find something suitable there. Something like *public interface Inter<T extends Inter<T>>* should work.

Comment: Could you rewrite the example using that approach?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: That kind of bound is basically NEVER useful in Java.

Comment: @newacct Yes, I'd shared in one of my (deleted) comments that what OP is probably trying to achieve could be done through a different design. But, it's always difficult to suggest re-factoring of design without the question sharing a good view of the problem domain. But, I do understand your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

You can try  something like this

```
public interface Inter<T> {

    public T doSomething();
}

public class C1 implements Inter<C1> {

    @Override
    public C1 doSomething() {
        return new C1();
    }
}

public class C2 implements Inter<C2> {

    @Override
    public C2 doSomething() {
        return new C2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I specify that the type of the return object has to be the
>   same as the object upon which the method is called?

You cannot do this in Java.